# Link popping up on page?

Tags: javascript, html, css, popup

```
<li><a href="#"><img src="img/example.jpg"></a></li>
```

So the above code is an image link. I'm trying to get it so when a user clicks on this image, instead of it leading them to another page for the content. It will bring up a box with the content in keeping everything on the same page? anyone know how you can do this?

Thanks

Comment: It sounds like you need to use Javascript to achieve your goals. You didn't mention that you can/cannot use JS - do you have any constraints as such?

Comment: I'm fairly new to JS but if anyone could point me to a library of such. I can read up on it and hopefully grasp what I need to do fairly quickly

Comment: What do you want to pop up? What content?

Comment: Its for a blog. So for each blog post I want an image and instead of the user clicking on the image and being sent away from the webpage. Each image will have a pop up with short content about that image kind of thing

Comment: Some popular solutions are http://fancybox.net/ and http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Misread, you could do something like this as well.

Hide the Content you want to display using
some css.

On click add a class to slide the hidden content into view.

here's a [JS fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fkrn60gb/)

css

```
.contentBox {
display:block;
position:absolute;
top:0;
left:0;
width:100%;
height:100%;
color:#fff;
background: rgba(0,0,0, 0.7);
-moz-transform:translateX(-100%) translateY(0px);
-webkit-transform:translateX(-100%) translateY(0px);
-o-transform:translateX(-100%) translateY(0px);
-ms-transform:translateX(-100%) translateY(0px);
transform:translateX(-100%) translateY(0px);
-webkit-transition:200ms ease;
-moz-transition:200ms ease;
-ms-transition:200ms ease;
-o-transition:200ms ease;
 transition:200ms ease;
}

.slideLeft {
 -moz-transform:translateX(0px) translateY(0px);
-webkit-transform:translateX(0px) translateY(0px)!important;
-o-transform:translateX(0px) translateY(0px);
-ms-transform:translateX(0px) translateY(0px);
transform:translateX(0px) translateY(0px)!important;
}
```

markup

```
<img class="clickthis" src="http://i.imgur.com/LULHwuJ.jpg" />

<div class="contentBox">
   The Content
</div>
```

js

```
$('.clickthis').on('click', function(){
  $('.contentBox').addClass('slideLeft');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a div that has an initial css value of visibility:hidden, then use javascript or jquery to change the value to 'visible' on a click event.

```
$('#yourpicturelink').on('click', function(){
  $('#hiddendiv').css('visibility', 'visible');
}
```

that could be expanded into more of a toggle function, but it should get you on the right path

Answer (score 0):

it sounds like you want to do something like this

```
 <li><a href="http:/blahblah.com" target="_blank" onclick="window.open(this.href,'targetWindow','toolbar=no,location=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,width=320,height=568');return false;"><img src="img/example.jpg"></a></li>
```

Comment: This does not fulfill OP's requirements. He/she specifically said "bring up a box with the content in keeping everything on the same page"

Answer (score 0):

Something like this is what you want. This is **very** basic, and doesn't have logic for closing the box or styling for the box, but hopefully you get the idea.

Basically, you have a div with the full size image you want to show that is hidden by default using css. Then, in the visible document, you have an image that shows the box using jQuery when it is clicked.

```js
$(function() {
  $(".clickable").click(function() {
    $("#box").show();
  });
});
```

```css
img.clickable {
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 10%;
  height:10%;
}

div#box {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img class="clickable" src="http://i.imgur.com/LULHwuJ.jpg" />

<div id="box">
  <img src="http://i.imgur.com/LULHwuJ.jpg" />
</div>
```

Or, as an alternative, you can simply learn how to use libraries already coded up for you to accomplish this. Look at the comment by @Nillervision for some examples.